# Angular2 change detection misunderstanding - With plunker

Tags: angular, plunker, angular2-changedetection

I'm trying to fully understand change detection with Angular2 final.

This include:

- Dealing with change detection strategies
- Attaching and detaching change detector from a component.

I thought I already got a pretty clear overview of those concepts, but to make sure my assumptions where right, I wrote a small plunkr to test them.

My general understanding about that where globally right, but in some situations, I get a little bit lost.

---

Here is the plunker: [Angular2 Change detection playground](https://embed.plnkr.co/tcgxSHsMgcWnQ7AQYK6C/)

**Quick explanation of the plunker:**

Pretty simple:

- One parent component where you can edit one attribute that will get passed down to two children components:
- On child with change detection strategy set to OnPush
- On child with change detection strategy set to Default

The parent attribute can be passed to children components by either:

- Changing the whole attribute object, and creating a new one ("**Change obj**" button) (which trigger change detection on the OnPush child)
- Changing the members inside the attribute object (**"Change content"** button) (which do not trigger change detection on the OnPush child)

For each child component, ChangeDetector can be attached or detached. (**"detach()"** and **"reattach()"** buttons)

OnPush child have an additional internal property that can be edited,
and change detection can be explicitly applied (**"detectChanges()"** button)

---

Here are the scenarios where I get behaviours that I cannot explain:

**Scenario1:**

1. Detach Change detector of OnPush Children and Default Children (click "**detach()**" on both components)
2. Edit the parent attribute firstname and lastname
3. Click "**Change obj**" to pass the modified attribute to the children

**Expected behavior:**
I expect **BOTH** children NOT to be updated, because they both have their change detector detached.

**Current behavior:**
Default child is not updated, but OnPush child is updated .. **WHY?**
It shouldn't because its CD is detached ...

**Scenario2:**

1. Detach CD for the OnPush component
2. Edit its **internal value** input and click **change internal**: Nothing happen, because CD is detached, so change is not detected... OK
3. Click **detectChanges()**: changes are detected and the view is updated. So far so good.
4. Once again, edit the **internal value** input and click **change internal**: Once again, nothing happen, because CD is detached, so change is not detected.. OK
5. Edit the parent attribute firstname and lastname.
6. Click "**Change obj**" to pass the modified attribute to the children

**Expected behavior:**
OnPush children should NOT be updated at ALL, once again because its CD is detached...CD should not happen at all on this component

**Current behavior:**
Both the value and the internal values are updated, seams like a full CD is applied to this component.

6. For the last time, edit the **internal value** input and click **change internal**: Change is detected, and internal value is updated...

**Expected behavior:**
Internal value should NOT be updated because CD is still detached

**Current behavior:**
Internal value change is detected... **WHY?**

---

**Conclusions:**

According to those tests I conclude the following, which seams strange to me:

- Component with OnPush strategy get **'changed detected'** when their input changes, **EVEN IF** their change detector is detached.
- Component with OnPush strategy get their change detector re attached each time their input changed...

What do you think about those conclusions?

Can you explain this behavior in a better way?

Is this a bug or the desired behavior?

Comment: No idea who downvoted. I think this is a pretty interesting question and the problem is perfectly explained.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think I saw it mentioned that `detach()` detaches the change detector for children, but not the component itself. I didn't dive that deep into change detection yet myself.

Comment: The doc say: 'Detaches the change detector from the change detector tree.'
Attaching/detaching CD work as expected with the child using default CD strategy

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update

> Component with OnPush strategy get 'changed detected' when their input
>   changes, EVEN IF their change detector is detached.

Since **Angular 4.1.1** (2017-05-04) `OnPush` should respect `detach()`

https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/acf83b9

### Old version

There are a lot of undocumented stuff about how change detection works.

We should be aware about three main **changeDetection statuses** (`cdMode`):

1) **CheckOnce** - 0

> `CheckedOnce` means that after calling detectChanges the mode of the
>   change detector will become `Checked`.

**AppView class**

```
detectChanges(throwOnChange: boolean): void {
  ...
  this.detectChangesInternal(throwOnChange);
  if (this.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce) {
    this.cdMode = ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked; // <== this line
  }
  ...
}
```

2) **Checked** - 1

> `Checked` means that the change detector should be skipped until its mode changes to `CheckOnce`.

3) **Detached** - 3

> `Detached` means that the change detector sub tree is not a part of
>   the main tree and should be skipped.

Here are places where `Detached` is used

**AppView class**

Skip content checking

```
detectContentChildrenChanges(throwOnChange: boolean) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.contentChildren.length; ++i) {
    var child = this.contentChildren[i];
    if (child.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Detached) continue; // <== this line
    child.detectChanges(throwOnChange);
  }
}
```

Skip view checking

```
detectViewChildrenChanges(throwOnChange: boolean) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.viewChildren.length; ++i) {
    var child = this.viewChildren[i];
    if (child.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Detached) continue; // <== this line
    child.detectChanges(throwOnChange);
  }
}
```

Skip changing `cdMode` to `CheckOnce`

```
markPathToRootAsCheckOnce(): void {
  let c: AppView<any> = this;
  while (isPresent(c) && c.cdMode !== ChangeDetectorStatus.Detached) { // <== this line
    if (c.cdMode === ChangeDetectorStatus.Checked) {
      c.cdMode = ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce;
    }
    let parentEl =
        c.type === ViewType.COMPONENT ? c.declarationAppElement : c.viewContainerElement;
    c = isPresent(parentEl) ? parentEl.parentView : null;
  }
}
```

Note: `markPathToRootAsCheckOnce` is running in all event handlers of your view:

[image]

So if set status to `Detached` then your view won't be changed.

***Then how works `OnPush` strategy***

> `OnPush` means that the change detector's mode will be set to `CheckOnce`
>   during hydration.

**compiler/src/view_compiler/property_binder.ts**

```
const directiveDetectChangesStmt = isOnPushComp ?
   new o.IfStmt(directiveDetectChangesExpr, [compileElement.appElement.prop('componentView')
           .callMethod('markAsCheckOnce', [])
           .toStmt()]) : directiveDetectChangesExpr.toStmt();
```

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.2/modules/%40angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/property_binder.ts#L193-L197

Let's see how it looks in your example:

Parent factory (AppComponent)

[image]

And again back to the **AppView class**:

```
markAsCheckOnce(): void { this.cdMode = ChangeDetectorStatus.CheckOnce; }
```

***Scenario 1***

> 1) Detach Change detector of OnPush Children and Default Children (click "detach()" on both components)

```
OnPush.cdMode - Detached
```

> 3) Click "Change obj" to pass the modified attribute to the children

```
AppComponent.detectChanges
       ||
       \/
//if (self._OnPush_35_4.detectChangesInInputProps(self,self._el_35,throwOnChange)) {
//  self._appEl_35.componentView.markAsCheckOnce();
//}
OnPush.markAsCheckOnce
       ||
       \/
OnPush.cdMode - CheckOnce
       ||
       \/
OnPush.detectChanges
       ||
       \/
OnPush.cdMode - Checked
```

Therefore `OnPush.dectectChanges` is firing.

Here is conclusion:

> Component with `OnPush` strategy get 'changed detected' when their
>   input changes, EVEN IF their change detector is detached. **Moreover
>   It changes view's status to `CheckOnce`.**

***Scenario2***

> 1) Detach CD for the OnPush component

```
OnPush.cdMode - Detached
```

> 6) Click "Change obj" to pass the modified attribute to the
>   children

```
See 3) from scenario 1 => OnPush.cdMode - Checked
```

> 7) For the last time, edit the internal value input and click change
>   internal: Change is detected, and internal value is updated ...

As I mentioned above, all event handlers includes `markPathToRootAsCheckOnce`. So:

```
markPathToRootAsCheckOnce
        ||
        \/
OnPush.cdMode - CheckOnce
        ||
        \/
OnPush.detectChanges
        ||
        \/
OnPush.cdMode - Checked
```

As you can see OnPush strategy and ChangeDetector manage one property - **cdMode**

> Component with OnPush strategy get their change detector re attached
>   each time their input changed ...

In conclusion I want to say that seems you're right.

Comment: Excellent explanation. There's an answer that explains the same thing on a post of Ben Nadel: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3114-change-detection-strategy-appears-to-override-the-changedetectorref-in-angular-2-rc-3.htm#comments_48356. This references the next github issue for this exact problem: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9720

Comment: Great explanation. There seems to be a missing image.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for this great answer, and for the related github issue! Now thats perfectly clear.